# Correct method to create a user on a local mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

wondering the difference between these two CREATE USER methods.

```
create user 'greg'@'local' identified by 'password952';
```

or would

```
create user 'greg' identified by 'password952';
```

suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are testable on a local MySQL installation. Generally speaking, though, the *correct* way to create a user account with MySQL would be like this:

```
CREATE USER 'greg'@'localhost'
       IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
```

If you are not using the native password function in MySQL, then you can remove `WITH mysql_native_password`. Many MySQL 8.x installations have it enabled by default, though.